# C++ inheritance hide method?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why we can not call this function Base::P(int)?

```
class Base
{   
protected:
    string s = "Base";
public:
    void P(int a){ cout << "Base" << endl; }
};
class Derived : public Base

public:
    using Base::s;  
    void P(){ cout << "Derived" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived a;
    a.P(2);   // Error, Why we can not use Base::P(int)?
}
```

Why we can not use Base::P(int)?

Comment: Why do expose the protected member `s` and not the hidden function with `using Base::P` ?

Comment: _"inheritance hide method?"_ as you notice yes.

Comment: You need `using Base::P;` in Derived. Don't know why, just the rule.

Comment: you can alternatively cast `((Base)a).P(2)` http://ideone.com/v55o02

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212190/c-issue-with-function-overloading-in-an-inherited-class

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628768/why-does-an-overridden-function-in-the-derived-class-hide-other-overloads-of-the