# How to overload a method in an inherited class so that the base class sees the inherited version?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, overloading

I'd like for an inherited class `B` to overload a member function `func()` of its base class, `A`. I know that when accessed by an object of `B`, then `B::func()` will be called and `A::func()` will be hidden unless explicitly referenced via `A::` or `using`.

Suppose now that `A` has another method `another_func()`, which calls `func()`. Assuming all members and inheritance are `public`, of course `B` will inherit `another_func()`.

Now if I call `func()` from `B::another_func()`, I want `B::func()` to be called, but when I try it, `A::func()` is called. Is there a way to achieve the behaviour I'm looking for, for the given code structure?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212190/c-issue-with-function-overloading-in-an-inherited-class), but it's not quite the same thing.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896830/why-should-i-use-the-using-keyword-to-access-my-base-class-method) is helpful in general, but doesn't really address my question.

In case the wording was confusing, here it is in code form:

Header:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:

    void func() { std::cout << "Called A::func()" << std::endl; };
    void another_func() { func(); };

};

class B: public A
{
public:

    void func() { std::cout << "Called B::func()" << std::endl; };

};
```

Source:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    B B_obj;
    B_obj.func();
    B_obj.another_func(); // I want this to call B::func?
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Called B::func()                                                                                                              
Called A::func()
```

The ouput I want is:

```
Called B::func()                                                                                                              
Called B::func()
```

The obvious answer is to directly do `B::func()` instead of `B::another_func()`, but my actual situation is more complicated, and it would be very useful for me to be able to do something similar to the above.

**Edit**
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c), I tried making `A::func` a `virtual` method, and it works the way I want. However, I have also read that virtual functions are much more expensive to call. Is there a better way?

Comment: Tried adding „this” in another_function?

Comment: Do you mean change the definition of `another_func()` to `this->func();`? I tried it, it produces the same undesired result.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried to override that function in B class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`virtual` is the only way for this(for now). You defined `class A` without any reference to possible derived classes of it. It's on `class B` you should define if a function from `class A` should changed and replace its own version of that function. The only way is make `class A` allow its derived classes to change a method. And it's by making that method `virtual`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:

    virtual void func() { std::cout << "Called A::func()" << std::endl; };
    void another_func() { func(); };

};

class B: public A
{
public:    
    void func() override { std::cout << "Called B::func()" << std::endl; };    
};
```

If it happens that you don't want to use `virtual` due to it's `slowness`. Imagine implementing this kind of behavior from scratch in assembly/machine-language. Or even redesign the architecture. You will end up making the same behavior with what's `virtual` is doing now. Provide a member pointer to a function that might be changed by derived classes.

---

**Edit**:

> *I have also read that virtual functions are much more expensive to call.*

No `virtual` methods are quite fast.
From Bjarne Stroustrup's [official website](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation):

> In my experience, the **efficiency reason is usually misplaced fear. In C++, virtual function calls are so fast** that their real-world use for a class designed with virtual functions does not to produce measurable run-time overheads compared to alternative solutions using ordinary function calls. Note that the virtual function call mechanism is typically used only when calling through a pointer or a reference.

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks.