# Inheritance and function overloading

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have some questions about inheritance and function overloading. I wrote some interfaces something like below. Now I'm trying to call some function of the parent class from derived class but it doesn't work as I intended.

Why is it possible to call `b.hello()` but not `b.test()`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void hello() {}
    void test() {}
    virtual void test(int a) {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void test(int a) override {}
};

int main() {
    B b;

    // Is possible to call test(int) through B
    b.test(1);

    // Is not possble to call test() through B
    b.test();

    // But, is possible to call hello() through B
    b.hello();
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? What changes have you tried?

Comment: when asking about code and error, please show the real code (you have missing `;` which lets me thing that your real code is different) and the error.

Comment: Because compiler tries to find `test` function in `B`, and when it finds it there, discovers that you try to call it without parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ issue with function overloading in an inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212190/c-issue-with-function-overloading-in-an-inherited-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it possible to call `b.hello()` but not `b.test()`?

There are member functions with the name `test` in both classes `A` and `B`. However, classes are scopes, and functions do not overload across scopes. Therefore, the overloaded set for the function `test` in `B` consists only of `test(int)`.

A member function with the name `hello` is, on the other hand, only present in class `A`, and `B` inherits this member function.

---

Note however that it is still possible to call `A::test()` on `b`:

```
B b;
b.A::test();
```

You can also bring `A::test` to the scope introduced by `B` with the `using` declaration:

```
class B: public A {
public:
    using A::test; // brings A::test() to this scope
    void test(int a) override {}
};
```

Now, `A::test()` can be called directly on `b` since the overload set for the function `test` in `B` consist of both `test()` and `test(int)`:

```
B b;
b.test();  // calls A::test()
b.test(1); // calls B::test(int)
```